# Choose a value from a set of columns based on value and create new column with the value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so if I have a pandas Dataframe like:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  a 
1  2  4  6  a
2  4  8  8  b
3  2  3  5  c
```

and want to insert row 'E' by choosing from columns 'A', 'B', or 'C' based on conditions in column 'D', how would I go about doing this? For example: if D == a, choose 'A', else choose 'B', outputting:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  a  1
1  2  4  6  a  2
2  4  8  8  b  8
3  2  3  5  c  3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is `lookup`

```
df.lookup(df.index,df.D.str.upper())
Out[749]: array([1, 2, 8, 5], dtype=int64)

df['E']=df.lookup(df.index,df.D.str.upper())
```

Comment: Does this translate to strings as well? If I had
`
    A    B    C   D 
0  a1  b2  c3  da 
1  a2  b6  c6  da
2  a4  b8  c8  db 
3  a2  b3  c5  dc
`

And conditions, if D == da, choose A, else D == db choose B, elseif D == dc choose C?

Comment: Sorry, bear with me, it's my first time using stack. Lookup is for array where the column and row labels are equal right? Could you use this to scale to a NxM array where n >> m, and the choice of columns would be lodged in the middle of the dataset?

Comment: @RoyHan what you mean scale a ?

Comment: @RoyHan I am not sure I understand your question ...Maybe it is better cclose this question(accept one of the answer check mark at the left ) ,and open a new one ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Currently I have a (1200, 10) of mostly string dataframe, and the goal is the append a column, say 'Z' to the df by check the value of the last column say 'Y' against 3 known options say 'A, B, C' which are not in the df, but have a corresponding column 'D, E, F'. Using column 'Y' which has either 'A, B, or C' I have to select from either 'D, E, or F' and append that value as column 'Z'. Thank you so much for answering my questions!

Comment: Okay I will do that, with a bit more clarity!

Answer (score 1):

`Lookup` will work here. This following examples return `integers` and `strings`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['x','y','z','x'],
    'B' : ['j','k','l','m'],
    'C' : ['n','o','p','q'],
    'D' : ['A','C','B','A'],
    }) 

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df.assign(E=df.lookup(df.index, df.D.map('{}'.format)))
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  x  j  n  A  x
1  y  k  o  C  o
2  z  l  p  B  l
3  x  m  q  A  x
```

Similar for `integer`

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : [1,2,3,4],
    'B' : [4,3,2,1],
    'C' : [5,6,7,8],
    'D' : ['A','C','B','A'],
    }) 

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df.assign(E=df.lookup(df.index, df.D.map('{}'.format)))
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  4  5  A  1
1  2  3  6  C  6
2  3  2  7  B  2
3  4  1  8  A  4
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = []
D = ['a','b','c']

for i in range(4):

    new_list = []

    for x in range(3):

        new_list.append(random.randint(0,10))

    new_list.append(random.choice(D))
    data.append(new_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Will give random data

```
IN[120]:df
Out[120]: 
   A   B  C  D
0  1  10  8  a
1  4   9  7  a
2  4  10  6  b
3  5  10  4  b
```

Then to add 'E' chose a one of the letters from D.

```
choice = random.choice(list(df['D'])).upper()


E = list(df[choice])

df['E'] = E
```

Returns

```
IN[122]:df
Out[122]: 
   A   B  C  D  E
0  1  10  8  a  1
1  4   9  7  a  4
2  4  10  6  b  4
3  5  10  4  b  5
```

you fix the data in D so that it includes all letter a to c. This was random